# response()->file() does not find files located at storage/app

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

This works perfectly:

```
return Storage::download('my_documents','test.pdf');
```

This doesn't work ("file not found error"):

```
return response()->file('/storage/app/my_documents/test.pdf');
```

How exactly do I have to define the path for the second approach?

I want to show the file directly in the browser. Can Storage class offers that functionality?

Please share solutions for Laravel 8+.

Thanks.

Comment: response()->download($path) you can do

Answer (score 1):

You must provide an absolute path to the `file()` method. You can use
`storage_path()` as configured in your `config/filesystems.php` file.

```
return response()->file(storage_path('app/my_documents/test.pdf'));
```

This should also work:

```
return response(file(storage_path('app/my_documents/test.pdf'));
```

---

Note: If you ever use the `app/public` folder, make sure you don't forget to create a symbolic link to your app public folder:

```
php artisan storage:link
```

Answer (score 0):

For file return need to specify full path like below.For example in this case file exist in `storage/app/public/pdf/1621869239k9y3aBE.pdf`

```
 return response()->file(storage_path('app/public/pdf/1621869239k9y3aBE.pdf'));
```

file() method accept two parameter like below

```
 /**
     * Return the raw contents of a binary file.
     *
     * @param  \SplFileInfo|string  $file
     * @param  array  $headers
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\BinaryFileResponse
     */
    public function file($file, array $headers = []);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `Storage` facade class has this functionality.
You can use method `response` instead of `download`. This sends a file directly to the browser instead of download.

In your case it will look like this:

```php
return Storage::response('my_documents','test.pdf');
```